# Moov atom relocate

Tags: php, html, video, mp4

I am working on a project for html5 video upload and play but I came accross the following problem:

> There are some videos which play after fully loaded and that is
>   because the `moov atom` is placed at the end of the file. Now, I need
>   to put this `moov atom` at the beginning of the video file.

After browsing the internet, I found [this](http://www.phpkode.com/source/p/dolphin-sns/plugins/moovrelocator/lib/Moovrelocator.class.php) library  which I want to include in my project. My problem is that I don't know how to include and use this library for processing my videos

Does anybody know something more about it? Please explain it to me because I searched all the Internet and didn't find explanation for this.

P.S. I know there exist programs for automatically swapping moov atom but I don't have an option to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you gave is part of a larger framework called Dolphin SNS:
http://www.phpkode.com/projects/item/dolphin-sns/

What you want to use is the MoovRelocator library by itself, which is actually by a different author (and happens to have been used by Dolphin SNS). Here's the link to the actual project page for MoovRelocator:

http://code.google.com/p/moovrelocator/

which states:

"If you need the demonstration-files (demo/demo.mp4 + demo/index.php) then you should download the archive-release (featured download)."

Hopefully you'll find this much easier to figure out now...